# Facebook re-request access-token possible?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm playing around with the Facebook-API. For authentication, the user will be sent to an oauth-dialog. After permitting access, the user's browser is redirected to an address specified in the facebook-application settings. We've requested scope=offline_access and response_type=token, so the post-auth redirect contains a valid access-token.
So far, so good.
Now my question: is it possible without user-interaction to re-request this access-token? (ex: the server did not catch the after-auth request from oauth-dialog)

Thanks for any enlightement :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, offline_access is deprecated - see here for more details: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/. The most you can get now is 60 days token.

Answering your question - it's not possible to request access token without user interaction - why would we need login dialog then?

Comment: Assuming an expired token (after 60days++), what has my application to do to get a new token? Redisplay the oauth-dialog?

Comment: if you use FB.login/init dialog, and user logs in before your 60-days token expires - then you transparently will get new short-lived token which you can exchange for new long-lived token. So user will not see oauth dialog (given that he has not removed your app of course). See more here (scenario 4): https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ and here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/ (check "init's the SDK with status: true to enable the checking of the user's authentication status at init-time" part)

Comment: Unterstood, so far. What I'm trying to find out is some kind of "best-practice" for creating an application for interacting with facebook. All solutions I've seen have to catch the post-oauth redirect to get the auth-token. Just for recap: it's not possible for an already authenticated application to get access to the information for which permission is already granted by the user?

Answer (score 2):

offline_access is deprecated and will be removed soon.

See here how you’ll probably have to adapt your application: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/